# How to the text in between of two values using regular expression

Tags: regex

I need help in extracting the text in between two values as my input using regular expression.

Here is my input:

```html
06.09.17 Saldo poczatkowe 0.00
Posiadacz rachunku: Adres korespondencyjny:
Data
Ksiegowa
Opis Transakcji Data Waluty Kwota
Winien Ma
1/18
Wyciag z rachunku :NESTLE POLSKA - PLATNOSCI C Numer wyciagu CitiDirect:172
Nr 67103015080000000500216417 PLN
Numer wyciagu :172
Data wydruku :06.09.17 Strona:
06.09.17 STAŁE ZLECENIE 06.09.17 195,895.20
Referencje : PL0SWZB162490032
Z/B 417-018
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 88.30
Referencje : PL0INE117249J4MJ
Nr Ref: 4249435900
Tytuł Płatnosci: FK 1048388520 F 1048393748
Kontr. : AUTO-BLAK SP. Z O. O.
FARBIARSKA 25A
WARSZAWA
Nr Banku: 17501123 RAIFF Centrum Operacyjne
Nr Rachunku: 06175000090000000010263654
Data Stempla 170906
Kwota Przekazu: 88.30 PLN
Info Code; 0003677116
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00
Referencje : PL0INE117249DJ20
Nr Ref: 4249174665
Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482
Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO
ul. Armii Krajowej 36/3
74-100 Gryfino PL
Nr Banku: 19500001 IDEA Centrala
Nr Rachunku: 94195000012006674284410001
Data Stempla 170905
Kwota Przekazu: 100.00 PLN
Info Code; 0005052946
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 302.58
Referencje : PL0INE117249J4IJ
Nr Ref: 4249435756
Tytuł Płatnosci: FAKTURA VAT 1048386446
Kontr. : PENSJONAT ANI - ANNA CHMIELOWSKA
UL. SPACEROWA 5
78-449 BORNE SULINOWO
Nr Banku: 10205561 PKOBP Oddział 56 w Warszaw
Nr Rachunku: 72102027910000720200892281
Data Stempla 170906
Kwota Przekazu: 302.58 PLN
Info Code; 0004647587
```

Now my problem is I want to get the value from **Info Code; 0005052946** to **06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00** hence I will be having this output instead:

```css
06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00
Referencje : PL0INE117249DJ20
Nr Ref: 4249174665
Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura vat 1048399482
Kontr. : FIRMA HANDLOWA TOP-ZOO
ul. Armii Krajowej 36/3
74-100 Gryfino PL
Nr Banku: 19500001 IDEA Centrala
Nr Rachunku: 94195000012006674284410001
Data Stempla 170905
Kwota Przekazu: 100.00
```

Do you have any idea how can I achieve my output? I've been looking for solutions and tutorials here in Sflow but couldn hardly see anything. Hope you can help me here.

By the way Info Code; 0005052946 is the only static value here.

Comment: `(?<=Info Code; 0005052946)[\s\S]*(?=Info Code;)` will get you that chunk. See it in use here: https://regex101.com/r/nMqjSK/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: C# but I don't have access to code. I can only use regular expressions

Comment: The expression you gave doesn't work. It still returned all input

Comment: @Dhenn you can see it in use if you click the link I added to my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. But it's getting the value after the info code. What I need is the values from the info code upwards until it reaches "06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 100.00"

Comment: @Dhenn, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you provide us with exactly the output you require?

Comment: Try  `(?-s)(?<=Info Code;.*\n)(?s).*?(?=Info Code; 0005052946\b)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, it works for the specific info code but when I tried with a different info code. It still gets the other chunk of text.

Comment: I need to get this chunk only:

Comment: 06.09.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 06.09.17 312.12
Referencje : PL0INE117249HBI9
Nr Ref: 4249351506
Tytuł Płatnosci: faktura nr 1048399994
Kontr. : animals katarzyna szwining ak 43 4
2-360 poraj
Nr Banku: 16800007 PLUS BANK S.A.
Nr Rachunku: 78168010170000300010311075
Data Stempla 170906
Kwota Przekazu: 312.12 PLN
Info Code; 0005020680

Comment: @Dhenn There is no `312.12 PLN` in the text you provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, I just provided a sample input, but my input was like that the amount is changing and the info code is changing.